# Magento get invoice number

Tags: magento, module

I'm trying to build a module for Magento that gets the invoice number. The main problem is that I get a Fatal error: Call to a member function getIncrementId() on a non-object...on line 19 ($invoice creation line). My Function is:

```
 $invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getInvoice()->getIncrementId();
    $last4 = substr($invoice, -4);

    $shipment = $observer->getEvent()->getShipment();
    $track = Mage::getModel('sales/order_shipment_track')
            ->setNumber($last4) //tracking number / awb number
            ->setCarrierCode('custom') //carrier code
            ->setTitle('Custom'); //carrier title
    $shipment->addTrack($track);
```

Comment: You need to clarify what event you are observing.

Comment: sales_order_shipment_save_before

Comment: It only has the shippment,you can try and use `$shipment->getOrder()->getInvoiceCollection()->getLastItem();` or fist invoice what ever you prefer.

Comment: I've tried using that function and invoice doesn't get a value. Sorry, is there something I need to add?

Comment: are sure that the order has an invoice? What does `count($shipment->getOrder()->getInvoiceCollection())` return?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the first line of code with this

```
$invoice = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
```

Using the getInvoice() method to get the order may be returning null which will give you the error you have on line 19.